# mapping deleted words back in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've folllowing datframe:

Column 1 contains names

Column 2 contains names after removing most occuring words(threshold>=4)

df1:

```
name                stripped_name
davids garden       davids garden   
xerox center        xerox
auto gas            auto
auto c gas          auto c
petroleum gas       petroleum
petrol gas          petrol  
gas engine          engine
money center        money
cyber cafe center   cyber   
cyber cafe          cyber
bahaar cafe         bahaar
coaching center     coaching    
cool cafe           cool    
bahar cafe          bahar
```

Suppose if i'm passing stripped name to a function which does fuzzy match and returns following result

df2:

```
p           s0 
auto c      auto
bahaar      bahar
petroleum   petrol
cyber       cyber
```

So if i've to map the names from df2.p, df2.s0 back to name column of df1,
there will be a value cyber which belongs to two names(cyber cafe and cyber cafe center).

How can I map this??
Can I get any suggestions on adding any intermediate layer to overcome abmiguity??

Following is the desired result :

```
p           p1                   s0     s 
auto c      auto c gas           auto   auto gas
bahaar      bahaar cafe          bahar  bahar cafe
petroleum   petroleum gas        petrol petrol gas
cyber       cyber cafe center    cyber  cyber cafe
```

Comment: Can you have your data given in a usable way? Use `to_dict` to the df you have.

Answer (score 0):

We assume `stripped_name` column in df1 is unique. Otherwise, there is no way for df2 to tell which to transform back.

```
s = df1.set_index("stripped_name")["name"] 
df2.apply(lambda x: x.map(s))
```

See [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)

Comment: will it work if there are duplicates in name(Eg. cyber appears two times in ndf1.name column)

Comment: @AvinashClinton think it would not work if that is the case. I think this would be your problem to define... which to transform back?